# SELECT STAR VS SELECT 1 in Oracle SQL to check existence

Tags: java, sql, oracle, performance

What is the better practice from the following queries for checking if a record exits when column ABC is 1 and why:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.ABC = 1

SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE A.ABC = 1
```

The query later gets passed on the application side and as we browse the result set (in java) i do this:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    found = true;
}
```

How can i build a test to prove which query performs better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `SELECT *`, you

1. Force the database to find the row and get its values (it can't rely on an index-only lookup, unless you have an index that includes all of the row's data, which makes no sense)
2. Serialize that to send back to the Java layer
3. Deserialize it at the Java layer

...all just to find out whether there's anything there.

`SELECT 1` lets the database look up the row based on an index and then *doesn't* force it to go fetch all of the row's data, etc.; there's less to serialize, less to deserialize.

Which do **you** think is better? :-)

Note that if there may be more than one row, you can go a step further. I'm not a PL/SQL guy, but if you use whatever PL/SQL uses to limit the `SELECT 1` to at most one row, you'll save some index seeking as well. [According to Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30787760/157247) and [this article on AskTom](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html), with Oracle that's by adding a `WHERE rownum <= 1` to it.

Comment: What about SELECT NULL VS SELECT 1

Comment: @otc: I don't know whether there's any better practice there. I've always preferred `SELECT 1` for this kind of thing, but that's usually because I'm using it in things like `EXISTS ( SELECT 1...)` and even though I **know** that works with `SELECT NULL`, I always have to think twice because I think of `NULL` as nothing.

Comment: So the records that come back will all be nulls vs having 1s in them. I would think a collection of nulls will be less (in terms of space) than a collection of 1s but just curious to know how will the database back end handle it in compile time and in execution time

Comment: @otc: I tend to doubt it would make any real-world difference. Either way it's going to involve metadata and then a quite small bit of actual value.

Answer (score 4):

Neither!  Both may return many rows and have to set up a result set.  Instead:

```
select 1
from a
where rownum <= 1;
```

This will return at most one row.

If you use `*`, then the database needs to return all the columns to the application.  That is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer:

```
select count(*)
from   my_table
where  rownum = 1;
```

... because it will always return a single row even if the table is empty, with a value of 0 or 1. This means you don't have to handle the NO_ROWS_RETURNED situation.